# Eloquent DB::Post->where()->update() returns 1 always regardless of any changes made

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to figure out how to properly code the update() function in eloquent to return either 0 or 1 based on user input in a form. For example, if I hit the update button without making any changes, it returns 1. Shouldn't it return 0?

I tried researching for solutions like here in stackoverflow to see if anyone has the same problem as I am facing. But so far not luck. I also tried modifying the code, but no luck.

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{

    $UCPost = UCPost::find($id);

    $UCPost->gown_2019 = $request->input('Gown2019');
    $UCPost->gown_2017_2018 = $request->input('Gown20172018');
    $UCPost->gown_2016 = $request->input('Gown2016');
    $UCPost->gown_2015 = $request->input('Gown2015');
    $UCPost->Light_Blue = $request->input('LightBlue');
    $UCPost->Seconds = $request->input('Seconds');
    $UCPost->Velveteen = $request->input('Velveteen');
    $UCPost->Velveteen_discolored = $request->input('Velveteen_discolored');
    $UCPost->Rental = $request->input('Rental');
    $UCPost->Rentals_Out = $request->input('Rentals_Out');
    $UCPost->Rentals_Left = $request->input('Rentals_Left');
    return $UCPost->where('id', $id)->update(
        [
            'gown_2019' => $UCPost->gown_2019,
            'gown_2017_2018' => $UCPost->gown_2017_2018,
            'gown_2016' => $UCPost->gown_2016,
            'gown_2015' => $UCPost->gown_2015,
            'Light_Blue' => $UCPost->Light_Blue,
            'Seconds' => $UCPost->Seconds,
            'Velveteen' => $UCPost->Velveteen,
            'Velveteen_discolored' => $UCPost->Velveteen_discolored,
            'Rental' => $UCPost->Rental ,
            'Rentals_Out' => $UCPost->Rentals_Out,
            'Rentals_Left' => $UCPost->Rentals_Left
        ]

    );
}
```

The code above as I mentioned earlier, it always returns 1 regardless of any changes made to the form. I want it to return 0 if there are no changes by the user or if they accidentally hit the update button. I'm trying to find the equivalent of mysqli_affected_rows in Eloquent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling the `update()` method on your model.  This will return 1 if the update was successful.  It doesn't matter if there were any changes made, always 1 on successful update.

If you would like to only save to the database if there are changes, you can use the `save()` method instead, which checks to see if changes are present, and only writes to the database if the data is different.  You have already created code to do this, by setting the model to have all of the new data from the sheet, so a simple `save()` at the end (with a check to see if it saves), will do what you want.

However, your current code is doing a *lot* of extra work.  You are assigning all the variables to the model, and then updating based on that assignment of data to the model.  You don't have to do all that assignment again in the update method.  Once you have set the fields, you can save immediately, you don't have to re-assign all the variables.  So:

```
$UCPost->gown_2019 = $request->input('Gown2019');
// etc..
$UCPost->Rentals_Left = $request->input('Rentals_Left');

$UCPost->save();
```

Will get you where you want to go and will only save if different.

If you have control over your form, and can change the form element names to match your database, this can be even easier.  You can do all of this in one line:

```
$UCPost->update($request->all());
```

If you want to check if the model is dirty just call isDirty():

```
if($UCPost->isDirty()){
    // changes have been made
}
```

Finally, if you want to verify if anything was changed after either method (save or update):

```
if ($UCPost->wasChanged()) {
    // changes have been made
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. It solved my problem. :)

Comment: Hey, by any chance do you know if Laravel offers sometime of function to do a sum based on a row not column. For example, I have a row with id of 1, and I have 5 columns with integers that I want to sum the total in row of id 1. Does that type of function exists?

Comment: I don't know of one, no.  With columns, its easy because it is like for like.  With rows, I can't see how this would work as it could be different types of data for each column within the row.  Might be worth a google, or a new question - but I think you will likely end up with a simple calc based on your specific row items and types ie: $item->col1 + $item->col2 + $item->col3 ... etc.  Sorry :)

Comment: @Watercyman Yes, I agree with columns is definitely easy. I will definitely do some Google searching and for a last resort, I'll ask a question here regarding that matter. Thank you for your advice and guidance. :)